# if else statement errors

Tags: php, loops, oop, if-statement

I am practicing php. SO today i am trying to do the image upload with validation. I am getting some problem in validation. here is my code

```
    <?php 
        if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($_POST['upload_btn'])){
          if(empty($_POST['up_image'])){
             echo "<p class='bg-danger'>Upload Your Image...!!!</p>";
          } else{
              $permitted = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
              $file_name = $_FILES['up_image']['name'];
              $file_size = $_FILES['up_image']['size'];
              $file_temp = $_FILES['up_image']['tmp_name'];

              $div = explode('.', $file_name);
              $file_ext = strtolower(end($div));
              $unique_name = substr(md5(time()), 0,10).'.'.$file_ext;
              $uploaded_image = 'img/'.$unique_name;

              move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image);
              $insert_img = $user->insert_image($uploaded_image);
              if(isset($insert_img)){
                 echo "<p class='bg-success'>Image Inserted Successfully...</p>";
    }
}    } ?>
```

when I upload image its return Upload Your Image...!!! when empty this is okay. But its also showing when I insert a image. I tried with removed the validation of empty, then I can successfully upload image. What to do in this case? Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change if condition to `if(empty($_FILES['up_image'])){`

Comment: @jitendrapurohit This is not working. if i send empty field then its upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `if/else` statement should do the trick

```
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($_POST['upload_btn'])){   
  if(empty($_FILES['up_image']['name'])) {
        echo "empty";
  } else {
        echo $_FILES['up_image']['name'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will always echo "Upload Your Image...!!" because you are checking

```
$_POST['up_image']
```

instead of

```
$_FILES['up_image']
```

This page should show you a few good examples of working with form uploads
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

To check if you have uploaded a file:

```
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["up_image"]["tmp_name"]);

if($check !== false){ then it has passed... }
```

Comment: This is not working. if i send empty field then its upload.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `if(!isset($_FILES['up_image'])){`.

Comment: its not working. when I send empty fields its not showing upload ur image! its directly upload without sending nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are uploading any file, your file details array are not in $_POST variable. Use $_FILES instead of $_POST.

As you written in your code $_POST['up_image'], replace this with the following 
$_FILES['up_images']